# angular 7 new project : ERR! code ETARGET ; No matching version found for @angular-devkit/

Tags: angular, npm, angular-cli, angular7

I'm new to angular 7, I used angular 2 2 years ago.. I just installed angular/cli and add it to my path.

Then, i tried a ng new helloworld to test but i get this error :

npm WARN deprecated circular-json@0.5.9: CircularJSON is in maintenance only, flatted is its successor

npm ERR! code ETARGET

npm ERR! notarget No matching version for @angular-devkit/core@7.0.4  (or other packages, it depends, can be in @angular-devkit/build-optimizer@0.10.4 or @ngtools/webpack@7.0.4; ...)

Which is strange, because when i look in the package.json of @angular-devkit, core version declared is 7.0.3...

Can someone help me please?

Thanks

[image of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zzk4a.png)

[ng --version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oMTXf.png)

Comment: what version of cli have you installed?

Comment: The version of my angular cli is 7.0.3

Comment: If you run `npm show @angular-devkit/core version`, is the version 7.0.4 shown in the list?

Comment: Nope, 7.0.3 is shown...

Comment: Okay, and what's the output of `npm config get registry`

Comment: the nexus of my company... http ://nexus..../repository/npm-all/

Comment: Okay, so it looks like that nexus doesn't have the up-to-date dependencies from the NPM registry. Version 7.0.4 was release 20 hours ago apparently

Comment: Okay so i hope it will be ok on monday morning?

Answer (score 1):

So you please follow given below steps.

1. Uninstall nodejs
2. goto C:\Users\ABCD\AppData\Roaming folder

   ABCD -> Username folder

   AppData -> hidden folder
3. Delete npm and npm-cache folder
4. Install nodejs.
   Note: not current nodejs
5. Check nodejs and npm version
   $node --version
   $nmp -version
6. Install angularjs
   $npm install -g @angular/cli
7. Check angular version
   $ng --version
8. Create new project
   $ng new projectName

wait for 5 to 6 minute. Don't press ctrl+c after below message
"npm WARN deprecated circular-json@0.5.9: CircularJSON is in maintenance only, fl                                                                                               atted is its successor."

9. After creating new project start server
   $ng serve
10. goto browser with url localhost:4200
11. Done.

Comment: Whole day is passed on this message

Comment: What issue you are facing. What did you do. if you have problem to upgrade angular version just type $npm install -g @angular/cli@latest

Comment: Everything was fixed on the monday morning. The nexus of my company was not up-to-date with new depedencies

Comment: - uninstall windows, - take the PC and leave the office, - demolish the office building, - rebuild the office building using eco-friendly materials, - jump of the roof of the new building